# PHP avoiding a long POST

Tags: php, html, post

This is more of a technique question rather than maybe code. I am having a php form with many fields (items to select). Naturally some of the items might be selected and some not. How do I know which ones are selected when i post the data from page 1 to page 2? I thought of testing each one if empty or not, but there are just too many fields and it doesn't feel at all efficient to use or code. 
Thanks,

UPDATE EDIT:
I've tried the following and maybe it will get me somewhere before I carry on testing the repliers solutions...

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="test" id="name" action="testprocess.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="choices[shirt]">
        <input type="text" name="choices[pants]">
        <input type="text" name="choices[tie]">
        <input type="text" name="choices[socks]">

        <input type="submit" value="submit data" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and then second page:

```
<?php
$names = $_POST['choices'];
echo "Names are: <br>";
print_r($names);

?>
```

This gives out the following:

> Names are:  Array ( [shirt] => sdjalskdjlk [pants] => lkjlkjlk [tie]
>   => jlk [socks] => lkjlkjl )

Now what I am going to try to do is iterate over the array, and since the values in my case are numbers, I will just check which of the fields are > 0 given the default is 0. I hope this works...if not then I will let you know :)

Comment: you mean avoiding many `isset($_POST['etc']))`?

Comment: loop through the array. if you build the form with an array it makes it easier to check what is posted.

Comment: yes @JackSpairow I want to avoid that for each posted item. If I use an array, so I will have to read each item in it and do a compare string so that I could decide the items in there and call their prices froom database. Again doesn't seem efficient because of the strcmp. Just expressing my thought here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is this:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="this" /> This
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="might" /> might
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="work" /> work
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And then in `submit.php`, you simply write:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $value) { 
  echo "{$value} was checked!";
}
?>
```

The square brackets in the name of the checkbox elements tell PHP to put all elements with this name into the same array, in this case `$_POST['checkboxes']`, though you could call the checkboxes anything you like, of course.

Comment: hmmm I dont get one thing...so this array is submitted....I check the values within it. but all fields in the form will be in the array I think...that doesn't solve it. Or only the fields with input will be included...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if this isn't the output you want, you may want to consider: 

`foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $key=>$value) { 
  echo "{$key} was set to {$value}";
}`

Comment: with little changes, this actually worked for me. I used to post array from html form, then there started playing with the content in foreach loop to ensure I get key and value. Thanks a bunch mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code so we would better understand what you want to do.

But from what I understood you are making a form with check boxes. If you want to see if the check boxes are selected, you can go like this:

```
if(!$_POST['checkbox1'] && !$_POST['checkbox2'] && !$_POST['checkbox3'])
```

This looks if all the three check boxes are empty.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid...with 100 fields, it becomes an issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
    <?php
function checkvalue($val) {
    if($val != "") return true;
    else return false;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $values = array_filter(($_POST), "checkvalue");
    $set_values = array_keys($values);        
}
?>
```

In this manner you can get all the values that has been set in an array..

Comment: hmmm could you maybe elaborate on that further? looks interesting...
thanks btw

Comment: Actually I think there may be some mistake..let me see first

Comment: now what is the checkValue and the set_values? and ok so I get the set values, but then how can that be used to $_POST['field'] know this for all values?

Comment: checkvalue is just a callback function for add_filter which checks if there are any fields with empty values and filters those out. So you get only the fields whose value have been set in the $values variable.Then the array_keys function gives you the names of all those fields in the $set_values array.

Comment: Now as you have all the fields that has been set in the $set_values you can iterate through them using foreach($set_values as $something).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Create a hidden input field within your form with no value. Whenever any of the forms fields is filled/selected, you add the `name` attribute of that field in this hidden field (Field names are saved with a  comma separator).

On doing a `POST`, you can read this variable and only those fields present in this have been selected/filled in the form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there an illustration to what stating here? again this seems very good technique...but a hint of how it's done would help too..

Comment: give me some time, will make a demo and get back to you.

Comment: It relies on Javascript - that some users may have disabled.

Comment: @sys-debug - I have made a demo for you here: http://codetidy.com/2484/. The post will echo only those fileds which are filled and their corresponding value. Let me know if

Comment: @ed-heal - yes, that might be true in some cases. Then, looping through all fields in server side code would be the only option.

Comment: You should never assume the client has something. JavaScript can help you, but you must never **rely** on it.

Comment: @Truth - You should never rely on anything coming from the client, including all the appropriate fields are there and contain sensible data. People have been known to try to circumvent any security, validation or verification done by Javascript. Best to assume from the servers point of view that Javascript is not working and you are going to receive gibberish. Do the checking at the server, use Javascript to give the user a better and more interactive experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure to understand your intention. I assume that you have multiple form fields you'd like to part into different Web pages (e.g. a typical survey form).

If this is the case use sessions to store the different data of your forms until the "final submit button" (e.g. on the last page) has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know which ones are selected when i post the data from page 1 to page 2?

is a different question from how to avoid a large POST to PHP.

Assuming this is a table of data...

Just update everything regardless (if you've got the primary / unique keys set correctly)

Use Ajax to update individual rows as they are changed at the front end

Use Javascript to set a flag within each row when the data in that row is modified

Or store a representation of the existing data for each row as a hidden field for the row, on submission e.g.

```
print "<form....><table>\n";
foreach ($row as $id=>$r) {
  print "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='prev[$id]' value='" 
     . md5(serialize($r)) . "'>...
}
```

...at the receiving end...

```
 foreach ($_POST['prev'] as $id=>$prev) {
     $sent_back=array( /* the field values in the row */ );
     if (md5(serialize($sent_back)) != $prev) {
          // data has changed
          update_record($id, $sent_back);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think this is a very complicated way of doing it mate...I don't even understand the solution I mean :(